# Kendo grid grouping message does not change

Tags: grid, kendo-ui, message, grouping

Hello and thanks in advance for any suggestions.
I am using the grouping option in the Kendo UI and i wanted to change the default grouping message :Drag a column header and drop it here to ...
So i changed the text in 3 .js files called: kendo.all.min.js, kendo.web.min.js, and kendo.groupable.min.js, to the desired text and the text does not change.
I think i'm missing something because when i group and un-group i see my message for a sec but then the grid reloads again and i get the original message again. Is the message coming from the dll or just from java script? hope someone can help it is really important.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you did it correctly and are loading the modified version of the JS it should work **BUT** that is not the way for localizing the message... KendoUI (in the latest versions) already has support for it. You should have done:

```
groupable: {
    messages: {
        empty: "Custom message text"
    }
},
```

as it is shown in their documentation [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#groupablemessagesempty-string)

Remember that if you modify their code, next time they release a new version you will have to merge their version with yours for having the fixes and new features that KendoUI team developed plus your changes.

**EDIT** If you want to have it for every Grid in you document, put at the very beginning of the JavaScript code:

```
kendo.ui.Groupable.prototype.options.messages =
        $.extend(kendo.ui.Groupable.prototype.options.messages,
                {empty: "Custom message text!"}
        );
```

Comment: Where should i set this in the desired page or can it be set for all the pages that use grid?